# How do I update my Visual Studio application automatically using ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, deployment, location, clickonce

I have made an application in Visual Studio 2015, in C#. It is a web browser, and I want it to update automatically. I visited the publish page, and got to the ClickOnce updates. It needs a update location. What kind of location? And how do I set it up? Please answer me quick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Update location is the place where the application should look for the update files (By comparing the local version with the version inside the files).

If your users are installing the application from a server (Local or remote), then you need to specify the location of your files.

Also, we need to set the following settings, go to project settings > Publish > Updates :

Tick: *The application should check for updates*

choose: *before the application starts*

Specify a Minimum version: use the current version.

Set the current version in Publish Version (Incremented By 1 from previous version).

Now publish your files, move them to location `XYZ` on the server. Let your users install from the url in this version. Then next time you release an update, do the same steps. and once the users launch the app, it should check for updates on the same location, if any newer version is found the application downloads the update.